# How to check if a typeid is a pointer at runtime?

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime, typeid, typeinfo

In C++, is it possible to determine if a `type_info` object describes a pointer at runtime? For example,

```
char a1;
char *a2;

const std::type_info &ti1 = typeid(a1);
const std::type_info &ti2 = typeid(a2);

std::cout << is_pointer(ti1) << std::endl;
std::cout << is_pointer(ti2) << std::endl;
```

would print `false` for `ti1` and `true` for `ti2`.

Obviously one could do `std::is_pointer<decltype(a1)>::value` but that requires that we have access to the variable identifier `a1`. What if we only have access to its `typeid` `ti1`?

Comment: `ti1 == typeid(char*)` ?

Comment: It has to be general not specific to `char`.

Comment: In all practical scenarios this decision can (almost) always be taken at compile time, I am dying to  know the use-case.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why would you only have access to an object's `typeid`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeid()` gives you a [std::type_info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) object. That's all.

As you can see in this documentation, `type_info` doesn't really tell you a lot. Pretty much anything of use there is "implementation defined".

And, there isn't anything there that tells you, authoritatively, whether the type is a pointer of some kind.

"Implementation defined" means that your C++ compiler defines what that means. It's very much possible that if you were to consult your compiler's documentation, you will find some additional explanation of what `name()` returns, and it may very well be possible to trivially determine, from `name()`, whether the type is a pointer. How, and in what way, depends entirely on your compiler and, of course, it will be completely non-portable.